# Passing values and return multiple values in php

Tags: php

HOw to Call Two Values from php Function with passing  some values to function

```
class insert //  Class for cheking
{
public function Read($variable)// Read Values From Database
{
//echo $variable;
$read=mysql_query($variable);

$r=""; // Var For Storage Multiple Values
$r1="";


while($res=mysql_fetch_array($read))
{
if($res["Temp"]=="Temp")
{
$r.=$res["Selection"].",";  
}
if($res["Temp"]!=="Temp")
{
$r1.=$res["Selection"].","; 
}
}// class close
```

and Now I am calling  function

```
$data=new insert();
$bar=$data->Read("passing Some MySql Code");
```

My Problem is how to call $r and $r1
Temp Is some Column in My MYsql Table and i am checking with that Temp='Temp'
where temp equal to or not equal to i want read out put

Comment: You question is very unclear! Do you ask how you can access `$r` and `$r1` ? (BTW: You don't return anything from you function)

Comment: Are you asking how you can expose $r and $r1 in a broader scope than the function?

Comment: Temp Is some Column in My MYsql Table and i am checking with that Temp='Temp' where temp equal to or not equal to i want read out put

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
class insert //  Class for cheking
{
    public function Read($variable)// Read Values From Database
    {
        //echo $variable;
        $read = mysql_query($variable);

        $data = array(); // Var For Storage Multiple Values

        while($res = mysql_fetch_array($read))
        {
            if($res["Temp"]=="Temp")
            {
                $data['one'] .= $res["Selection"].",";  
            }
            if($res["Temp"]!=="Temp")
            {
                $data['two'] .= $res["Selection"].","; 
            }
        }

        return $data;
    }
}// class clos

//Call

$data=new insert();
$bar=$data->Read("passing Some MySql Code");

echo("<p>bar:one = ".$bar['one']."</p>");
echo("<p>bar:two = ".$bar['two']."</p>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so if I get this right you want to access the value of r1 & r after calling the function.
Either put $r & $r1 in an array an return it or set $r & $r1 as class properties with appropriate getter & setters.

**First method**

[...]

```
if($res["Temp"]!=="Temp")
{
$r1.=$res["Selection"].","; 
}

return new array("r" => $r, "r1" => $r1); 
}// class close
```

Then

```
$data=new insert();
$bar=$data->Read("passing Some MySql Code");
echo $bar["r"];
echo $bar["r1"];
```

**Second method**

```
class insert //  Class for cheking
{
  private $r;
  private $r1;

public function getR(){
    return $this->r;
}
public function getR1(){
    return $this->r1;
}

[...]
```

Then replace every occurrence of `$r` & `$r1` by `$this->r` & `$this->r1` and use it like so

```
$data=new insert();
$bar=$data->Read("passing Some MySql Code");
echo $data->getR();
echo $data->getR1();
```